# Javascript regex optional on left or right

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I can't get my pattern to work correctly. I want to detect if a specific word has any word/letter either in left or right side or both.

For example:

- a{placeholder} = found
- {placeholder}b = found
- a{placeholder}b = found
- {placeholder} = not found

This is my pattern so far `(\w)?\{LINK_TO_WEB_VERSION\}(\w)?`

https://regex101.com/r/hX4lM0/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the patterns combined with the delimiter `|`

```
\w\{LINK_TO_WEB_VERSION\}\w?|\w?\{LINK_TO_WEB_VERSION\}\w|\w\{LINK_TO_WEB_VERSION\}\w
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hX4lM0/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
/^(?!\B{LINK_TO_WEB_VERSION}\B).+$/gim
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hX4lM0/3)

Comment: this string: 'xyz {LINK_TO_WEB_VERSION}' should be false. Your regex is returning true

Answer (score 0):

You have more options

1: with an or condition (|) you can say, match all with letter before or letter after as follows: /(\w){placeholder}|{placeholder}(\w)/img
if you have one of them, is found, you not need match before AND after ;)

2: negate all stuff: find placeholder with no letter before and no letter after: /[^A-Z]{placeholder}[^A-Z]/img => not found, any other case mean found

You not need look behind or look ahead, in my opinion, but you can use it if you want: `/(?<!\w)\{placeholder\}(?!\w)/` , but be careful, look behind is not supported by some languages (f.e. javascript).